# Будут ли в обобщающее слово входить прилагательные?

Tags: синтаксис, обобщающее-слово

Немного не ясно, входят ли прилагательные в обобщающее слово.

*На берегах рек возникли **древние русские** города: Киев и Новгород.*

Comment: Это же обобщающее слово, а не фраза.

Answer (score 1):

> **Обобщающее слово** — это слово или словосочетание, которое является общим обозначением находящихся при нём однородных членов.
> <...>
> **Обобщающие слова** всегда являются тем же членом предложения, что и однородные члены, при которых они находятся, потому что они выполняют одну и ту же синтаксическую функцию. Разница между ними заключается только в том, что они обозначают понятия разных объёмов.

*На берегах рек возникли древние русские **города**: Киев и Новгород.*
Обобщающее слово "города" (без прилагательных) в этом предложении является подлежащим. Подлежащими же являются и названия городов "Киев" и "Новгород".

"Древние" и "русские" — это определения. Их можно заменить другими (древнейшие, славянские) или изъять из предложения. Смысл не изменится — города все равно возникли.

А вот если обобщающее слово, например, выражено счетным оборотом (три причины, несколько правил) или устойчивым сочетанием (фразеологизмом), то таких действий произвести нельзя.

*В приемном пункте их было **трое, три женщины**: одна на приемке белья, другая на выдаче, третья на выписке квитанций и получении денег* (А. Рыбаков).
*Он был **мастер на все руки**: слесарь, столяр, плотник и даже механик* (В. Короленко).

[Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/237-obobwayuwieslovapriodnorodnyhchlenah.html)